# Google chrome developer tool dosen't shows the DOM inside the body

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom

[image: Image showing DOM not loading]I

I have created a simple HTML page with materalize.css, when I open it in Google Chrome browser, the page loads properly but there is no HTML visible under body tag in developer tools.

Comment: you have two errors in your console

Comment: is the content in the `#shadow-root` ?

Comment: hey @t.niese  content is not visible in #shadow-root as well

Comment: @smnbbrv those 2 errors are from youtube embed and completle independent of ythis issue.

Comment: @MrinalJain I know that I had such a problem recently too, but I think it was gone after a reload or restart. But I don't know if that was in Chrome. Might be a bug in the developer tools.

Comment: I would disable all of your shiny extensions and try again. There is some probability one of them is responsible for that

Comment: @smnbbrv   tried doing that too. It doesn't work